# not displaying the updated page

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer

Uploaded a flash site on server, it still shows me an old swf file instead of new, and it is happening in my office at other places it is showing the new uploaded file

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a caching issue, which is common for most sites (and especially common for Flash since it's highly inefficient and heavy - caching saves the server and client a lot of work).

Try clearing your cache in your browser (or trying another browser, private session, etc.)  On most browsers, you can hit <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd> or <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+R</kbd> to clear it out (You could replace <kbd>F5</kbd> with <kbd>R</kbd> in many cases as well).  Otherwise, in the options/preferences for your browser you can tell it to clear cache explicitly.